# Uniform convergence of functions and sets of zeros.

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that we have a sequence of holomorphic non-constant functions $(f_{n}(z))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $F(z)$. These functions are defined on a connected open set $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ that includes imaginary axis.

I see that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $F$ on any compact subset of $A$

Additionally $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup\{|Re(s)|:f_{n}(s)=0, s\in A\}=0$$

Where $Re(s)$ is a real part of complex number $s$

My question:

> Do the statements above imply that all the zeros of $F(z)$ are purely imaginary. This is $F(z)=0\implies Re(z)=0$ ? If not, what is conterexample and how the assumptions should look like?

I have an intuition that zeros of these functions move closer to the imaginary axis just like the whole functions, but i don't know how to prove it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: for $F-f_n$ nonconstant one must have $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{C}}|F(z)-f_{n}(z)|=\infty$ so your condition is not attainable unless $F=f_n+a_n$ when the problem is trivial; maybe you want $f_n$ converges normally to $F$?

Comment: Thank you for important issue. I am editing my question in a momet

Comment: this is just immediate from Hurwitz theorem ($F(w)=0, |\Im w|=a > 0$ pick a disc centered at $w$ of radius $a/3$ so it is at a fixed distance from the real axis; by Hurwitz $f_n$ must have a zero in there from some $n$ on so one contradicts the hypothesis